# Did a United States government official state that refusal to recognize the ICC was due to fear of George W. Bush would be prosecuted?

Tags: united-states

In a recent edition of *Time* Magazine - I cannot find the article online, nor do I have access to a print copy anymore - a short article regarding the actions of the International Criminal Court (ICC) against African dictator stated that members of the United States government refused to let the United States recognize the Court because they feared the President George W. Bush might be prosecuted for war crimes related to the war in Iraq.

Regardless of the actual motivations behind the United States' decision, did any government official actually claim this?

Comment: I would be grateful if anyone could find the exact quote or a link to the article.

Comment: http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2014/jul/17/facebook-posts/are-george-w-bush-dick-cheney-unable-visit-europe-/  this is slightly ontopic for your review.

Comment: This question is unclear. The title is about motivations (off-topic) but the body disclaims that. Are you asking if the Time magazine article is right about this claim, or are you asking us to just find out whether the article exists, and matches your memory?

Comment: @Oddthinking He's asking, is there's evidence that any government official stated that as a reason? I assume that Americans spoke mostly about the possibility of American military personnel being indicted, so maybe the question is whether any government official also ever mentioned a possibility that the American President (and in particular, President Bush) might be.

Comment: Trying to demonstrate that the above is a notable claim, [this page](http://www.amicc.org/usicc/bush) for example alleges that the following were among the claims made by the Bush Administration: `Claim: The ICC could investigate and prosecute US leaders for the "crime of aggression."` and `Claim: The Court could be politically motivated against US leaders and soldiers.`

Comment: @Oddthinking - It seems that the title was just poorly worded, given the precise wording of the body.

Comment: *Which* government official? There must be many thousands!?

Comment: @Oddthinking Sorry, I was unexpectedly away. I was asking about whether or not an official ever made such a statement, not whether or not that motivation ever existed.

Comment: @ChrisW Yes, your first comment is accurate.

Comment: @Sklivvz I wish I could find the original article to see if there were specifics. I don't recall if anything about the official was mentioned; either way, the question is about the sources behind the statement in the article.

Comment: @DVK Yes, I wrote the title quite poorly.